# How to check if something from one table in not used in another

Tags: postgresql, foreign-keys, primary-key

I have three tables:

```
CREATE TABLE activities (
activity varchar(20) Primary key
);
```

with data:

```
Table_Tennis1
Table_Tennis2
Table_Tennis3
```

and

```
CREATE TABLE times (
time varchar(5)
);
```

with data

```
09:00
10:00
11:00
12:00
13:00
14:00
15:00
16:00
17:00
18:00
19:00
20:00
```

and finally

```
CREATE TABLE planner (
day varchar(9) foreign key
time varchar(5) foreign key
activity varchar(20) foreign key
member bigint foreign key
);
```

and Primary Key = (day, time, activity)

with data

```
friday,09:00,Table_Tennis1,4
friday,10:00,Table_Tennis2,2
```

I was wondering it was possible to find out all the Table_Tennis rooms that are not being used at a certain time on a certain day, or all rooms that have not yet been booked on all times for one day.

so it should give me a result_set of

```
09:00, Table_Tennis2, Table_Tennis3
10:00, Table_Tennis1, Table_Tennis3
11:00, Table_Tennis1, Table_Tennis2, Table_Tennis3 ect ect
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> all the Table_Tennis rooms that are not being used at a certain time
>   on a certain day,

```
SELECT activity
FROM   activities a
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM   planner p
    WHERE  p.activity ~~ 'Table_Tennis%' -- may or may not be needed
    AND    p.day  = 'friday'
    AND    p.time = '09:00'
    AND    p.activity = a.activity -- was missing in my 1st draft
    );
```

---

> all rooms that have not yet been booked on all times for one day.

```
SELECT a.activity
FROM   activities a
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT activity
    FROM   planner p
    WHERE  day = 'friday'
    GROUP  BY 1
    HAVING count(*) = 12 -- assuming there are exactly 12 slots
    ) p USING (activity)
WHERE p.activity IS NULL; -- excludes all fully booked rooms
```

Or:

```
SELECT activity
FROM   activities a
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT activity
    FROM   planner p
    WHERE  day = 'friday'
    GROUP  BY 1
    HAVING count(*) = 12 -- assuming there are exactly 12 slots
    );
```

**But not:**

```
SELECT activity
FROM   activities a
JOIN (
    SELECT activity
    FROM   planner p
    WHERE  day = 'friday'
    GROUP BY 1
    HAVING count(*) < 12
    ) p USING (activity);
```

... because that would drop rooms with no entries for the day at all.

---

You might consider using

```
slot time
```

instead of

```
time varchar(5)
```

`time` should not be used as identifier. It is a [reserved word](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-keywords-appendix.html) in all SQL standards and a type name in PostgreSQL.
Also, the [data type `time`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-datetime.html) is a better fit for your purpose and occupies less space than `varchar(5)`.

And

```
 day date foreign key ...
,slot time foreign key ...
```

instead of

```
 day varchar(9) foreign key ...
,time varchar(5) foreign key ...
```

The names of weekdays would let you cover one week. I assume you want more than that.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but all those three answers do are give me a list of the activities table

Comment: @DannyCalladine: I substituted * with `activity`. Equivalent according to your definition.

Comment: still not working it only gives me full list of all activites, if we use the friday at 09:00, table_tennis1, i would like it to either create a result set of, table_tennis2, table_tennis3 or the who list of activites minus table_tennis1

Comment: @DannyCalladine: Sorry, there was a WHERE clause missing. Fixed and should work now (tested it).